# Setting up GitHub Action to run only on .py files in the pull request

Tags: python, github-actions, workflow, githooks, github-for-windows

I am trying to setup GitHub Action that should only run on .py file in the pull request. Suppose if I am pushing any other file (say .txt) it should skip the workflow run and allow me to merge the pull request despite it is on protected branch rule for required checks.(I have added a branch protection rule so that the pull request should only get merged once the status checks have passed).

I have added path to just run the checks on files with .py extension but this halts the check in pending state for non python files and the pull request can never be merged

```
name: Linter
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '**.py'
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  linter:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install flake8
      - name: Lint with Pylint
        run: |
          flake8 $(git diff origin/main --name-only --diff-filter=d)
```

Comment: See this https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc

Comment: I am not able to see the files under workflows

Comment: there are two workflows (linter and no-linter) that do the work. There are two sample prs (#7 and #6) that show one blocked by the failing lint and the other one is not blocked

Comment: ok thanks for that.. Can you also show me which workflow is marked as required in the branch protection rule

Comment: Yes, just `linter` since the name is the same one of these will always run

Comment: but in Status checks that are required. Does it not take the checks through file name?? for me it is searching only the file name and If I give linter, no linter is never run

Comment: It worked!! thank you @Matteo